# fail2ban works fine on bad SSH attempts, but fails on bad Apache2 attempts

Tags: apache-httpd, fail2ban

I'm running Debian Linux. `uname --all` shows:

```
Linux xxx.xx 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:33:32 UTC 2014 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running `sshd` on a port that is not 22.  I've updated `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` to point to the new `sshd` port.  It works fine.  I can try and login to that port with an ssh client, enter the wrong password several times, then it locks that IP address out via iptables.

However, I am also running an apache webserver, that gets hit all the time with attempts like this (from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:13 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/muieblackcat
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:14 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:16 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:16 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/pma
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:16 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/myadmin
[Sun Nov 02 08:03:17 2014] [error] [client 178.239.62.113] File does not exist: /var/www/html/MyAdmin
```

I was trying to setup fail2ban to read error.log and ban the offending IP addresses via iptables, but I can't get it to work.

Like I said, it works great for ssh, but not for apache.  Here is my jail.local:

```
[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 67.159.128.0/19
# bantime = 21600 == 6 hours
bantime  = 21600

#findtime, in seconds.  300 = 5 minutes, 10800 = 3 hours
findtime = 10800
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification. Available
# options are "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# yoh: For some reason Debian shipped python-gamin didn't work as expected
#      This issue left ToDo, so polling is default backend for now
backend = auto

#
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = root@localhost

#
# ACTIONS
#

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define 
# action_* variables. Can be overriden globally or per 
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-multiport

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail

# Default protocol
protocol = tcp

#
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
          %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s]
           %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=

%(logpath)s]

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in     

jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section 
action = %(action_)s

#
# JAILS
#

# Next jails corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban 0.6 which
# was shipped in Debian. Enable any defined here jail by including
#
# [SECTION_NAME] 
# enabled = true

#
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.
#
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local

# we are banning port xxxxx instead of ssh because I use port xxxxx instead
[ssh]

enabled = true
port    = xxxxx
filter  = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
findtime = 300
maxretry = 4

#
# HTTP servers
#

[apache]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-auth
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log
findtime = 10800
maxretry = 3

# default action is now multiport, so apache-multiport jail was left
# for compatibility with previous (<0.7.6-2) releases
[apache-multiport]

enabled   = true
port      = http,https
filter    = apache-auth
logpath   = /var/log/apache2/*error.log
findtime = 300
maxretry  = 3

[apache-noscript]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-noscript
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log
findtime = 300
maxretry = 4

[apache-overflows]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = apache-overflows
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log
findtime = 300
maxretry = 2

[apache-misc]

enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = apache-misc
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log
findtime = 10800
maxretry = 2
```

Here is my /etc/fail2ban/apache-misc file:

```
[Definition]

failregex = <HOST>.*"[A-Z]* /(cms|user|muieblackcat|db|cpcommerce|wp-login|joomla|    awstatstotals|wp-content|wp-includes|pma|phpmyadmin|myadmin|mysql|mysqladmin|sqladmin|    mypma|admin|xampp|mysqldb|pmadb|phpmyadmin1|phpmyadmin2).*"
        <HOST>.*\" (502|500|417|416|415|414|413|412|404|405|403|401|400)

ignoreregex = .*\"GET \/(press|mailto|domestic|word).*
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be doing this? One of my sites gets File Not Found messages for most visitors as it doesn't have a favicon in all the required formats.  You'll need to make sure that all types of favicons are covered to make sure you don't lock out genuine visitors - all Apple devices seem to need their own peculiar versions of icon files, depending on model! IE needs `favicon.ico` etc, etc.  Your `fail2ban` setup will need to be quite specific as to which `File Not Found` messages to ban.

Comment: Linux 2.6? Past time to upgrade to 5.10 for that nftables speed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with a small subset of regex conditions using the recommended syntax as follows...

```
failregex = [[]client (?P<host>\S*)[]] File does not exist: .*/(muieblackcat|phpmyadmin)
```

You can always build on it and can easily test your regex.  Don't forget to reload fail2ban once you make the changes.

Comment: Thanks!  I put your failregex line in above, restarted fail2ban, and my /var/log/fail2ban.log file shows: fail2ban.actions: WARNING [apache-misc] Ban 1.2.3.4 (ip address of my smartphone).  But for some reason, I can still "get in" from my smartphone.  Almost like iptables isn't working.  I know it is when I try it via an SSH client.

Comment: Have you checked your iptables rules to see if there are any issues there?

Comment: try manually adding rules in IP tables for few bad IPs and check